# Can we create .NET application to build an object detection model?

Tags: ml.net-model-builder

Since ML.NET Model Builder now supports object detection for local CPU or GPU, can we build a our own .NET application that trains object detection models using ML.NET?
ML.NET already provides tools for building image classification trainers. I was wondering if we can do the same for object detections.

Thanks